# jQuery - change .show to .slideUp on page load with a 3 second delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I have a pop up set with a cookie which shows on page load. However i wish to change the .show to .slideUp with a 3 second delay after page load.

Here's my code:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
// function to show our popups
function showPopup(whichpopup){
if (document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)doSomethingOnlyOnce\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1") !== "true") {
$('.overlay-content').slideUp( 300 ).delay( 800 );
//display your popup background and set     height  to   the page height
document.cookie = "doSomethingOnlyOnce=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT";
console.log("cookie not found.");
}

}
// function to close our popups
function closePopup(){
$('.overlay-content').hide(); //hide the overlay
}
// hide popup when user clicks on close button
$('.close-btn-new').click(function(){
closePopup();
});
showPopup(null);
});

</script>
```

Comment: something like this? https://plnkr.co/edit/u7ZkivQNId8uT5h0ADQ0?p=preview  if you want the popup on the bottom of the page, just move it out of the container div

Comment: I've tried the above but not successful. any pointers will be much appreciated. please see my code edit.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say :

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
  $('.overlay-bg-lookbook').slideDown();
}, 3000);
```

slideUp is for hiding.

Comment: I want the popup to slide up from the bottom of the page 3 seconds after the page has loaded

Comment: Down is for showing, Up is for hiding
To give the impression of sliding form the bottom, you will need to position the popup with absolute position on the bottom of a container.
So when the popup will show with the slide effect, it slides toward the top.
My english is so bad :)

Comment: When I use .slideDown the div doesn't slide up however when i use .slideUp it works fine with the reverse effect any idea why? (i have edited my original code to show what im using)

Comment: According to the doc, slideUp is for hiding http://api.jquery.com/slideup/
It just change the element's height to 0.